# Entity Framework code first can't update database after setting foreign key as nullable

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am having trouble updating my database using EF code first after I set foreign keys (ProcessID and SubProcessID) of my model as nullable.

Here's the model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long MyModelID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Process")]
    public int? ProcessID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sub Process")]
    public int? SubProcessID { get; set; }

    //... some more properties here

    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
    public virtual SubProcess SubProcess { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the migration code after I add migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID", "dbo.Process");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID", "dbo.SubProcess");
    DropIndex("dbo.MyTable", new[] { "ProcessID" });
    DropIndex("dbo.MyTable", new[] { "SubProcessID" });
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID", c => c.Int());
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID", c => c.Int());
    CreateIndex("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID");
    CreateIndex("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID", "dbo.Process", "ProcessID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID", "dbo.SubProcess", "SubProcessID");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID", "dbo.SubProcess");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID", "dbo.Process");
    DropIndex("dbo.MyTable", new[] { "SubProcessID" });
    DropIndex("dbo.MyTable", new[] { "ProcessID" });
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    CreateIndex("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID");
    CreateIndex("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID", "dbo.SubProcess", "SubProcessID", cascadeDelete: true);
    AddForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID", "dbo.Process", "ProcessID", cascadeDelete: true);
}
```

The error message that I am getting is this:

```
Table 'MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable' doesn't exist
```

**Note:** I only failed to update-database when I set these foreign keys as nullable int. But if I make it as int, I can update-database successfully.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but in `Up`, I think `AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "ProcessID", c => c.Int()); AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "SubProcessID", c => c.Int());` should be fine by itself. (Also, for your `Down` to actually work, you'll need to give your rows with nulls in the foreign key column some non-null reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone of you having the same issue as me, Here's my solution to my problem:

In Migrations folder > Configuration.cs:

I changed Configuration constructor to this:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
    CodeGenerator = new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
}
```

And update-database now works!!

If anyone of you having trouble using code-first approach using MySQL, I am willing to help! :)